# Weird font rendering under specific sizes

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am setting the size of the headings with the combination of `rem` and `vmin` units to make them look perfectly sized on any device:

```
h5 {
    font-size: calc(1rem + .25vmin);
}
```

This means that the h5 heading will be at least 1rem big plus .25vmin. This proved to be an awesome solution and works everywhere from IE10 and up and other latest browsers.

The problem I face though is that at specific screen resolutions the font may look weird:

[image]

While it normally looks like this:

[image]

The example above is the HKGrotesk font, however it happened to other fonts as well.

I am pretty sure it has to do something with value roundings, however AFAIK I cannot round values in the calc function.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but in your ruleset, what is the actual rule being set? Also, could you try to make a live example? Maybe using some hardcoded sized iframe?

Comment: @Kaiido, sorry it's the font-size, completely missed that. You can preview the iframe here: https://jsfiddle.net/6a0sswon/3/.  You can see that the Checkout heading (right under the logo) looks bumpy. You can also try to resize the iframe to 1920x1200px for example to see that it looks good on other resolutions.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Because with just the code given, I cannot reproduce this behaviour.